# Multiple html table generation from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table structure like this (lets say tableA):

```
unitID, Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, Value5, Value6, Value7, Value8.
```

I create a data table using the following code.

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .tbstyle {
            border: 1px solid #CCC;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            float: left;
        }

        .tbstyle td {
            padding: 3px;
            margin: 2px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            text-align: center;
            height: 13px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <table class="tbstyle" id="">

        <?php

  include ("config.php");

  $sql = "SELECT Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, Value5, Value6, Value7, Value8 FROM tableA ";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
   {
        echo   "</td><td>". $row["Value1"] . "</td><td>" . $row["Value2"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Value3"]."</td><td>" . $row["Value4"]."</td><td>" . $row["Value5"].
            "</td><td>" . $row["Value6"]."</td><td>" . $row["Value7"]."</td><td>" . $row["Value8"]. "</td></tr>";
   }

      echo "</table>";

} else { echo "0 results"; }
$conn->close();

    ?>

    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

I have another mysql table (lets say tableB) which has saleID. I would like to generate above table side by side as many as the number of saleIDs on tableB.

and I need to make each generated `<table id="">` to have a unique saleID. I mean table IDs should be named with saleID. I left the table id in the code blank.   `<table class="tbstyle" id="">`

I'd really appreciate any help I can get. Thanks.

[image]

Here is my current code which is not complete and doesn't give the expected result:

```
<table class="tbstyle" id="">

 <?php

$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

 $sql="SELECT saleID FROM tableB";

if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
  {

  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);

  }

  $sql = "SELECT Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, Value5, Value6, Value7, Value8 FROM tableA ";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 

      for ($x = 0; $x <= $rowcount; $x++)  

   {

        echo   "</td><td>". $row["Value1"] . "</td><td>" . $row["Value2"]. "</td><td>" . $row["Value3"]."</td><td>" . $row["Value4"]."</td><td>" . $row["Value5"].
            "</td><td>" . $row["Value6"]."</td><td>" . $row["Value7"]."</td><td>" . $row["Value8"]. "</td></tr>";
   }

      echo "</table>";

} else { echo "0 results"; }
$conn->close();

    ?>   

</table>
```

Comment: That looks more like the structure of a spreadsheet than a mysql table

Comment: it may not be ideal table design. but it is a simple and small scale.

Comment: 1- You are missing quite a lot of HTML here.  `<table>` should have a `<tbody>`, you should have `<tr>` lines right now you only have `<td>` cells.  2- your logic is quite hard to understand, remember we have no background of what you are trying to do.  Put examples.  Add an image of your wanted design.  3- for your table id, when you query your tableB, you will have the saleID of each row, so you can create your `<table>` in the loop reading the results.

Comment: Table: http://www.html5-tutorials.org/tables/thead-tbody/ or https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp

Comment: thanks, @Nic3500. I included a picture to make it clearer, also included a sample table html output in the picture.

Comment: Simple and small scale maybe, but it must be a headache to maintain. How do you know whether a value belongs in column 4 or column 7, and what happens when value9 shows up?

Comment: I understand what you mean. but this is just a sample data. and I added a picture to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is my suggestion.

1. `SELECT saleID FROM tableB ORDER BY saleID`.
2. loop on the results.  For each saleID, do...
3. echo the start your table (`<table>, <thead> ... </thead><tbody>`)
4. `SELECT * FROM tableA`.
5. Loop on these results.  For each row, echo one row of the table (`<tr><td>...</td>...</tr>`).
6. Close your table (`</tbody></table>`).

So you loop twice, once for tableB, again for tableA.  Each saleID is a new table, in the inner loop.

One detail which is still unclear to me, is where is the link between tableA and tableB.  How do you know the values in tableA apply to the saleID you just read?  Anyway my answer is strictly or the HTML-PHP version, no database logic here.

Comment: thanks, Nic3500. I will try your suggestions. but my php and mysql knowledge is limited. I already tried some of these searching the internet but couldn't get a successful result.  There's no link on tableA and tableB. it is not necessary. tableA is static like periodic table. I just need it to be repeated.

Comment: ok, I added my current code the original post that I'm trying now. you can see it there too.

Comment: In your new code, you reuse variable names, confusing the code IMHO.  Use $sql1, $sql2, $result1, $result2, ... to know which result set you are actually looping on.  And do not forget to start your table HTML after each saleID.  Also why loop with a while, then another time with a for?  2 loops only, one for saleID, one for values.